# Gradle 6.0 and PMD 6.15 integration , how to fail the build when allowed violation limit breaches

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, ant, pmd

I am working on migrating the build process of Java project from Ant to Gradle

For failing the ant build when pmd violations breaches a pre-defined limit, we are using **thresholdFile**, which has a pre-defined limit of violations.

Similarly, maven provides **failOnViolation** and **maxAllowedViolations**  attributes to achieve the same. [Maven Docs](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/check-mojo.html)

I am referring to [Pmd Docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.Pmd.html). However couldn't find anything on similar lines.

Is there an equivalent way to achieve the same PMD behavior in Gradle

Comment: The PMD gradle task internally uses [PMD's ant task](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_tools_ant.html). However, there is no property "thresholdFile". Are you using the standard PMD ant task or do you currently use a custom ant task to execute PMD?

Comment: I am using the pmdMain task in gradle. Here I am looking at something similar to maxRuleViolations as mentioned in the PMD's ant task

Comment: Here is the snippet from my build.gradle 

 pmdMain {
  consoleOutput= true  
  ignoreFailures = true
  pmdTest.enabled=false
  incrementalAnalysis = true
  rulePriority=1
  ruleSets = ['category/java/bestpractices.xml','category/java/codestyle.xml','category/java/design.xml','category/java/documentation.xml','category/java/errorprone.xml','category/java/multithreading.xml','category/java/performance.xml']
}

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I achieved it by defining a custom task as mentioned below.
Here based on the pmd violation report, I was able to calculate the violations found in the current iteration

```
task checkPMDReport  {
    doLast {
        def pmdReport = rootProject.file('reports/pmd/main.xml')
        def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parse("$pmdReport")
        def bugsFound = rootNode.children().children().findAll({node -> node.name() == 'violation'}).size()
        if (bugsFound > "$BUG_THRESHOLD") {
            throw new GradleException("$bugsFound PMD rule violations were found. See the report at: $pmdReport")
        }
    }
}
```